# Read a Data Frame into a Separate Function from Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny application which lets a user upload a CSV to undertake sentiment analysis.

## The Aim:

I want to use Shiny to upload the CSV and then use a separate function (CapSent) to do the analysis and output the results.

Basically I am trying to pass the 'df' uploaded by the user into the function 'CapSent' (which resides in global.R) from Shiny. CapSent undertakes Sentiment analysis using a custom dictionary of words.

## My Code So Far:

So far I have:

ui:

```
library(shiny)
source('global.R')
ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarPanel(

            # Input: Select a file ----
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                 ".csv"))
    ))
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$contents <- renderTable({
            req(input$file1)        
            df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                            header = input$header,
                            sep = input$sep,
                            quote = input$quote)   

            CapSent(0.1, df) # 0.1 represents a threashold, df is the data

            })
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Functions.R:

```
CapSent <- function(0.1, df){

    newdf<-data.frame(df,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    #....Do some sentiment analysis here on newdf

    #....Then export the sentiment analysis results
    write.csv(newdf,"myResults.csv")

}
```

## The Issue

With the above code I receive the error 'Error in Encoding<-: a character vector argument expected'.

'CapSent' works when I manually add 'df' to the Global Environment (using readr) but I want users to upload their own data to analyse. Hence the question:

### Is there a way to pass df to the Global Environment from Shiny?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`ui.R`

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input:  ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
      actionButton("button", "Apply function/download df"),
      hr(),
      uiOutput("downloadButton")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      h2("ORIGINAL DATA FRAME"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("contents"),
      br(),
      uiOutput("modify")


    )
  )
)
```

`server.R`

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  temp_df <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)
  temp_df2 <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)



   output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({

      req(input$file1)
      temp_df$df_data <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, sep = ";")

      temp_df$df_data

  }, options = (list(pageLength = 5, scrollX = TRUE)))

  output$contents2 <- DT::renderDataTable({

    temp_df2$df_data


  }, options = (list(pageLength = 5, scrollX = TRUE)))

  observeEvent(input$button,{
    if(!is.null(temp_df$df_data)){
      temp_df2$df_data <- CapSent(temp = 0.7, temp_df$df_data)

      output$modify <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          h2("MODIFY DATA FRAME"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("contents2")
         )
      })

      output$downloadButton <- renderUI({
         downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
      })
     }else{
      showNotification("No data was upload")
     }

  })



  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() { 
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(temp_df2$df_data, file)
    })

}
```

as I do not know which `CapSent` end-use I made `CapSent` a function that adds a new column in the original data frame;

`global.R`

```
CapSent <- function(temp = 0.1, df){

  newdf <- df
  newdf$New_Col <- temp
  return(newdf)
  #....Do some sentiment analysis here on newdf

  #....Then export the sentiment analysis results
  #write.csv(newdf,"myResults.csv")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a global function/variable just make a global.R which will let you use the function/variable everywhere on the ui.R or server.R.

This is the link to learn more: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Edit: If you want to show the CSV, first of all you need to make a tabpanel and then make a table using the csv data like:

Use the package DT, install.packages("DT), is a package to make dynamic tables.

```
`output$yourtabpanelid = DT::renderDataTable({
      req(input$file1)

      df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                     header = input$header,
                     sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote)
        return(df)
    })`
```

Then don't make a functions.R, just put the function below the one and put the read.csv(.....) before the function to use it in all functions at server.R like:

```
`df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                         header = input$header,
                         sep = input$sep,
                         quote = input$quote
```

)
server <- function(input, output, session) {`

And you can quit the df <- read.csv.... of the function DT but keep the return(df)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the link does not really explain why the code will not trigger. I have changed the script to global.R and still get nothing back as an output?

Comment: what are you trying to show and what are you trying to do with myFunction()

Comment: tell me if u have some problem with that answer or u need another result, i will try to solve it

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried to clarify my original question above. You will see that myFunction() is now CapSent() which undertakes Sentiment analysis on the uploaded csv. As you might see, I am only starting out with Shiny so might not have it set up correctly. Appreciate your time on this.